# Programming: Verb for #include, build in Diploma thesis

Tags: word-choice

For my diploma thesis in engineering I describe some programming. One thing is that I want to describe which libraries can be included. The German *inkludiert* sounds very old. *Eingefügt* does not get the point? Or do it indirect with *Präprozessordirektiven*... Well I don't want to go down that road. Articles like Wikipedia evade the verb form in this context.

So how can I say:

> 1. The xyz libraries can/must be included.
> 2. The program is built with the makefile xy.
> 3. Build process for abc...
> 4. Passing parameters

Edit: Passing parameters to a function is also frequently used, to say *übergeben* a lot is almost impolite. Is there a better word?

Comment: Warum ist "ubergeben" unhöflich? Es ist doch klar, dass hier keine Körperfunktion gemeint ist.

Comment: As it is for a diploma thesis: which terms does your professor use? I know that some of them have a strong opinion on what the correct translation for these expressions is...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First I wouldn't translate some words especially when talking about programming. There are too many expressions without a corresponding translation in german (some simply sound strange to a native speaker/german programmer). For example as far as I could see there is no/good translation for `Build process` (e.g. `Der Build Process findet täglich um 03:30 Uhr statt` was commonly used in my company) or `compiler`.

But answering your question:

1. Die Bibliotheken xyz müssen eingebunden werden/sein
2. Das Programm wird mithilfe des makefiles xy gebaut
3. As I said, *I* wouldn't translate this
4. Übergebene Parameter is just fine and imho the correct translation.

Concerning 4) Perhaps you could alternate `übergeben` by either using `benötigten Parameter` if they are required or `die Funktion erhält xyz als Parameter`

Comment: What about Erstellungsprozess?

Comment: Never heard someone using `Erstellungsprozess` in the context of compiling code. However I know that the german wikipedia article is using this word. I wouldn't use it.

Comment: Well, "Build Process" looks wrong. You'd have to change the spelling.

Comment: Thanks for your help!
But what if a function includes a struct into another struct, e.g. fooIncludeMyBar()? Then 'einfügen' is the better translation?

Comment: Ich finde weder Build Process noch Erstellungsprozess besonders schön und würde vielleicht ein Nomen an dieser Stelle vermeiden und statt dessen zB schreiben "alle Programme werden jede Nacht automatisch übersetzt und getestet".

Comment: Also `bauen` geht ja gar nicht. Ich habe die Informatiker an der Uni und in meinem sonstigen Umfeld immer nur von `kompilieren` reden hören.

Comment: komplilieren und bauen sind ja eigentlich verschiedene Dinge. Obwohl ich anstatt bauen, zusammensetzen benutze: Das Programm wird jede Nacht kompiliert und zusammengesetzt (entspricht link), als Nomen könnte Bauvorgang dienen (entspr. build process)

Comment: ad 2: "übersetzen" wäre der typische Jargon, zumindest für "compiling". "Building" often include more than that; dafür kenne ich keinen stehenden (deutschen) Begriff.

Comment: @Toscho: es gibt aber Unterschiede zwischen "build" (alles erneut generieren und zusammenfügen, egal ob geändert oder nicht), "make" (Nur noch nicht übersetzte oder geänderte Teile generieren, dann alles zusammenfügen) und "compile" (eine oder mehrere Dateien in ein Objektformat übersetzen). Die deutschen Begriffe für "build" und "make" kenne ich allerdings auch nicht.

Answer (score 4):

Die vermutlich üblichsten Ausdrücke im Zusammenhang mit Bibliotheken, Modulen etc. sind:

- einbinden
- hinzufügen

Comment: Bibliotheke werden tatsächlich eingebunden (vom sog. Linker), aber Header-Dateien nicht. Sie sind ja nicht die Bibliotheke (Dateien im einem Binärformat), sie beschreiben nur deren Inhalt, als Text.

Comment: Diese Unterscheidung mag technisch richtig sein, aber selbst für Header-Dateien ist der üblichste Ausdruck "einbinden". Google-Suche: "Header-Datei einbinden" (567 Treffer); "Header-Datei importieren" (453 Treffer);  "Header-Datei hinzufügen" (360 Treffer); "Header-Datei inkludieren" (160 Treffer).

Comment: Tja, dann wird da wohl oft die m.E. falsche Terminologie benutzt. Kann man nix machen.

Answer (score 2):

You can safely use *inkludieren* for `#include`, the action the compiler does can be called *einziehen* or *einbinden* (although I would use the latter rather used for libraries than include files - Note, you don't `#include` libraries but rather header files. You would *link* to libraries)

"Build Process" I would probably translate as *Erstellungsprozess* or simply call it *Build*.

And "parameter passing" is *Parameterübergabe*

1. Die Header-Datei[en] der Bibliothek[en] xyz muss/müssen/kann/können eingezogen werden / Die Bibliotheken xyz müssen eingebunden werden
2. Das Programm wird mittels des Makefiles xy gebaut/erstellt
3. Der Erstellungsprozeß für xy
4. Parameterübergabe

Comment: Eingezogen (Einziehen) klingt für mich falsch. Eingefügt (Einfügen) klingt da schon vertrauter. Vielleicht geht auch noch Einbezogen (Einbeziehen).

Comment: @RudyVelthuis Das mag sein - aber es ist der klassisch verwendete technische Term (möglicherweise noch aus der Zeit, als man Bänder verwendete). *einbeziehen* würde nur transportieren, dass das "irgendwie damit zu tun hat", *einfügen* ist eher eine Aktion, die man mit einem Editor machen würde.

Comment: Google übersetzt "include" mit "einschließen". Klingt gar nicht mal so schlecht, IMO.

Answer (score 0):

(1) Die Lib/Bibliothek wird *eingebunden. Sie müssen die xyz Lib *einbinden*. Binden Sie die xyz Bibliothek ein, sonst fehlen Symbole. Und so weiter.

(2) Das Programm wird mit dem Makefile xy.mak *erstellt*. Erstellen Sie das Programm!

(3) Das *Erstellen* (verb as noun) von abc … dauert ewig. (takes an eternity to compile)

(4) Parameter werden *übergeben*. Übergeben Sie der Funktion folgende Parameter: HINSTANCE, UINT, PCWSTR. Und so weiter.

Comment: I wouldn't recommend **erstellen** for compiling. I'd stick with [kompilieren](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/kompilieren), as it is more precise and less likely to be misunderstood.

Answer (score 0):

"inkludieren" ist nicht alt, das ist eine Form, die sehr gerne verwendet wird. In so mancher C-Anleitung wird sogar "Inkludedateien" verwendet. Wirklich korrektes Deutsch ist es aber m. W. n. nicht.

Comment: Worauf bezieht sich denn dein "wirklich korrektes Deutsch" - Auf "inkludieren" - das steht so im Duden, oder auf "Inkludedateien" - das ist jetzt wirklich nicht so gängig

Comment: Dann eher Include-Dateien, oder Header-Dateien.